# decorators in python

Tags: python, decorator

I am trying to understand the functioning of decorators. What am i doing wrong in the following code. Please do correct it

As I have understood when aFunction() is called it in turn calls myDecorator() which also makes a call to afunction(). Right?

Also how to pass parameters into afunction()

```
class myDecorator(object):

    def __init__(self, f):
        print "inside myDecorator.__init__()"
        f(1) # Prove that function definition has completed

    def __call__(self):
        print "inside myDecorator.__call__()"

@myDecorator
def aFunction(*a):
    print a
    print "inside aFunction()"

print "Finished decorating aFunction()"

aFunction(2)
```

Comment: Thorough explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators

Comment: If you need more help with decorators and annotations see my blog post here. http://blog.mattalcock.com/2013/1/5/decorates-and-annotations/

Answer (score 4):

```
class myDecorator(object):

    def __init__(self, f):
        print "inside myDecorator.__init__()"
        # save a reference to the real function, so it can be called later
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "inside myDecorator.__call__()"
        # call the real function and return its result
        # passing it any and all arguments
        return self.f(*args, **kwargs)

@myDecorator
def aFunction(*a):
    print a
    print "inside aFunction()"

print "Finished decorating aFunction()"

aFunction(1)

print "Finished calling aFunction()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `__call__` method is missing the parameter, which you give to `aFunction`.

```
class myDecorator(object):

    def __init__(self, f):
        print "inside myDecorator.__init__()"
        f(1) # Prove that function definition has completed
        self.__function = f

    def __call__(self, *args):
        # the *args magic is here to mirror the original parameter list of
        # the decorated function. But it is better to place here parameter list
        # of the function you want to decorate, in order to minimize error possibilities
        print "inside myDecorator.__call__()"
        return self.__function(*args)

@myDecorator
def aFunction(*a):
    print a
    print "inside aFunction()"

print "Finished decorating aFunction()"

aFunction(1)
aFunction('a', 23, 42)
```

Comment: You should return the result of the function from `__call__`. There is also most likely no need to use name mangling here -- you may even want people to be able to access the wrapped function. You're assuming the function doesn't take any keyword arguments.

Comment: @agf I agree with the return, but as for the "visibility" of the function member and the function parameters, it depends on the real environment.

Answer (score 1):

`f`, in `__init__`, needs to be saved, then the `__call__` method needs to call it.  Something like this:

```
class myDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        print "inside myDecorator.__init__()"
        self.f = f
        print "function has been saved"
    def __call__(self, *args):
        print "inside myDecorator.__call__()"
        result = self.f(args)
        print "done with f()"
        return result

@myDecorator
def aFunction(*a):
    print a
    print "inside aFunction()"

aFunction(1)
```

What happens with decoration is that the original function is *replaced* with whatever the decorator returns.  Your original code, however, was not saving any reference to `aFunction` so it was getting lost.

Comment: You're assuming any decorated function takes no keyword arguments.

Comment: @agf, No, I know his does not, since he had none in there.  It is not always necessary to code for the most general case.